# Calculating conjugacy classes.

Tags: group-theory

I have 2 questions to ask from a past paper, I used to really understand how to compute conjugacy classes, but I haven't studied group theory since november, and the only notes I have, have it in a confusing manner using $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, …$ and I can't remember how to work it out and I have a group theory exam tomorrow.

The first question is;
**Suppose that the order ofG is prime power. From the class equation show that G is not simple.**

Secondly, **Let G be the alternating group on 5 symbols, work out the conjugacy classes and find their sizes. Show that G is simple.**

[image] 
This is all I am given as my example, but I do not know where any part of it came from.

If someone could talk me through this that would be amazing, I only left it until last minute as I thought I could do it but it turns out I do not follow the notes at all.

Thanks

Comment: Your first question is addressed explicitly at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class#Conjugacy_class_equation; the second is proved in Section 3 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/Ansimple.pdf

Comment: The problem might be the link between conjugacy classes and the class equation? In that case: conjugation grives an action of a group $G$ on itself.

Comment: as for the link about computing conjugacy classes, much like my lecture notes it is merely an example of what the conjugacy classes are not how they are found?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for the first problem**

The class equation reads

$$|G| = |Z(G)| + \sum_i [G:C_G(x_i) ] \,.$$

As $[G:C_G(x_i)]\neq 1$, it follows that $ |G|$ and each $[G:C_G(x_i)]$ is divisible by $p$. From here you get that

$$|Z(G)| \neq 1$$

Thus, either $Z(G)$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $G$ or $Z(G)=G$. The problem should be easy to finish from here....

Comment: okay, thanks i get that, any help with conjugacy classes?